# Can i resize the pyqt5 window by stretching it and keeping the original aspect ratio (without layouts)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I made a ui that dont uses layouts but when i made it full screen buttons just stayed top left corner and seemed very small.

Pixelation doesn't matter for me i just wanna make things bigger. (when the resolution is 1920x1080 it'll be normal but when we made it 4k, things will be 4x bigger)

Is stretching all the window content possible with pyqt5?

Like this example that i made in mspaint:

[image]

[image]

> main code ⬇️

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys
from converted_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()

        # Initialize the user interface
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> converted_ui ⬇️

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 250, 250))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(465, 170, 106, 46))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lorem Ipsum"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Most UI toolkits (specifically, those that mainly target computers) don't provide means to keep a fixed aspect ratio for UI elements because their intended purpose is to keep logical layout and usability above other aspects (functionality over esthetics). There are many reasons behind this, including the minimum required size of each widget depending on system configuration (DPI, font family/size and system font scaling), which prevents having a fixed ratio that could potentially make the UI completely unusable. Then, window management is quite different depending on the platform: while »

Comment: » some OS allow fixed aspect ratio for windows, not all of them provide such a feature in a reliable way (most notably, Linux, which can arbitrarily force a window size), and since Qt aims to provide full cross-platform compatibility, this was never implemented. You can only provide a `sizeHint()` or explicitly call `resize()` to a preferred target size, eventually based on the available screen sizes, but that won't limit the user resizing in any way. So, while you could **try** to do this in a `resizeEvent()` override, reality is that it will be almost certainly unreliable because you only »

Comment: » considered *your* configurations and assumptions, not the hundreds of possible combinations of other user configurations, and it will eventually make your UI almost (or completely) unusable, if not possibly *ugly*. So, my suggestion is to not think too much about this: use existing layout managers, they have a robust implementation that is always reliable and provides deterministic results (the UI is *usable*, which is the most important aspect). In the meantime, learn more about them, so that you can eventually find a compromise between what they do well and what you want as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and the [**resizeEvent()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) method is where you
you can change the size and location of widgets.

But this is not practical and it is better to use [**layout managers**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

#from converted_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
# ---------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <----  
#       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 250, 250))      
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 200, 200))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
# ----------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <----        
#       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(465, 170, 106, 46))
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 60, 200, 200))
        
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lorem Ipsum"))
        

class MainUI(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #1E5F74; color: #47F5E1;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.w = 800
        self.h = 600
        self.x = 80
        self.y = 60
        self.setMinimumSize(self.w/3, self.h/3)
        self.widthFactor  = 1
        self.heightFactor = 1
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widthFactor  = self.rect().width() / 800
        self.heightFactor = self.rect().height()/ 600  
        w = self.w * 0.25 * self.widthFactor

        self.pushButton.resize(w, w)
        self.pushButton.move(self.x * self.widthFactor , self.y * self.heightFactor)
        
        self.label.resize(w, w)
        self.label.move((self.x * self.widthFactor + w * 2), self.y * self.heightFactor)

        super(MainUI, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainUI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have a few questions:
1) Can i make move and resize dynamic for all the buttons that i have in my gui?
2) How can i lock aspect ratio so it'll be always for example be 16:9?

Comment: Can I project my main window to another main window and resize all things accordingly? Is this possible?

Comment: @AbdullahEsadTAN You asked a question and provided sample code.
I answered your question.
If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour
If you have other problems, ask a new question.